# TinyMCE: style dropdown and content of a custom style differently

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have made a custom style named "Drop Cap" which in the content I have of course styled it with a very large font size. But in the Formats dropdown menu I don't want it to use the same very large font, I want it to just be normal. Here you see the problem:

[image: example showing tinymce editor with problematic menu]

How do I fix this? It looks like tinymce automatically takes the CSS from content_style for that style and applies it "statically" to the style attribute for that element in the dropdown! And there are no decently named classes or anything that I use to override that styling...

My JS code is:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',
  style_formats_merge: false,
  style_formats: [
    {"title":"Subheading","block":"h5","classes":"subheading"},
    {"title":"Drop Cap","inline":"span","classes":"dropcap clearfix"}
  ],
  content_style: '.dropcap { float: left; font-size: 4.6em; padding-right: 3px;  line-height: 95%; }'
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/TheStoryCoder/L8av738L/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `preview_styles` configuration option for TinyMCE:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#preview_styles

You can use that to control how much of the formatting you want functional in the menus and select lists in TinyMCE.

Comment: That is a very limited solution and it won't work in my case because for other styles in the dropdown I *do* want to retain the font-size - which is the one I would want to remove to fix the issue in question...

Comment: Not sure how you would propose that the editor know to sometimes do something and other times not ... as the editor code is open source you can always modify it to do what you need.

Comment: It's very simple - if the editor just had generated proper classes etc instead of hardcoding the style attribute it would be easy to distinguish between the dropdown, the various dropdown options, and the content.

Comment: You could try wrapping the Drop Cap styles in another element like `#editorID .dropcap, #page .dropcap {}` where `#page` wraps your whole content.